# django-filter (django rest framework) - method filter with 3 parameters

Tags: methods, filter, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I'm using django rest framework to create an api and django-filter to provide nice way for users to see how filters work in the browsable api part of the site.

I have a need to filter queryset by a result of a method call. Unfortunately it needs 3 parameters to be provided by the user (calculate distance from centre point using lat, lng, radius).

I know I can declare a non model field in the filterset with a method to call but then just one parameter is passed to the method.
I can declare 3 non model fields but then I end with 3 different methods or calling the same one with 1 changing parameter 3 times.
example code:

```
class PersonFilter(FilterSet):
    status = ChoiceFilter(field_name='status', choices=Person.STATUS_CHOICES)
    # I show an example of what I need to achieve below, obviously it will not work as
    # I need to give the user 3 fields to fill in and call the method only once with their values...

    latitude = NumberFilter(label='latitude', method='check_if_in_range')
    longitude = NumberFilter(label='longitude', method='check_if_in_range')
    radius = NumberFilter(label='radius', method='check_if_in_range') 

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = 'status', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'radius'
example method to filter by 3 parameters:

def check_if_in_range(self, queryset, name, value):
    here I need access to the values from 3 non model form fields...
    do calculation and filter the queryset
        return <filtered queryset>
```

Is this even doable?
I want my users to be able to use:

```
<base_url>?longitude=234234&latitude=232342&radius=34
```

to filter persons through the API...
Thank you for your time & help!

Tomasz

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
class PersonFilter(FilterSet):
    status = ChoiceFilter(field_name='status', choices=Person.STATUS_CHOICES)
    radius = NumberFilter(label='radius', method='check_if_within_range')

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = 'status', 'radius'

    def check_if_within_range(self, queryset, name, value):
        base_point = Point(latitude=float(self.request.GET.get("latitude")),
                           longitude=float(self.request.GET.get("longitude")))
        return queryset.distance_within(base_point, value)
```

Based on how you want to calculate the distance and filter queryset you need to have a custom method. Here I have assumed you'll have `distance_within()` method in your custom queryset manager.

You can refactor as per your need/structure.